# Render JSON data onto ejs view with Expressjs

Tags: json, node.js, express, render

I am trying to get 2 values from a JSON file on to the webpage.
obj["fruit"]  and obj["thyroid"]. I use ejs as the template view engine and expressjs.

The below method says "fruit" and "thyroid" are undefined. The console.log works though.

```
app.post('/top', function (req, res) {
    var obj;
    fs.readFile('./object.json', 'utf8', function (err, data) {
        if (err) throw err;
        obj = JSON.parse(data);
        console.log(obj["fruit"]);
        console.log(obj["thyroid"]);

    });
    res.render(
        'disp.ejs',
        { 
            food: obj["fruit"]
            name: obj["thyroid"]

        }); // render
});
```

Comment: readFile is an asynchronous operation, put the res.render code inside the function callback for fs.readFile

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[fs.readFile](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_readfile_path_options_callback)(path[, options], callback) is the asynchronous way to read a file. The way your code is setup node will start reading the file and immediately then call res.render before the file `data` is finished reading.

If you put the res.render inside the callback it will only be called when the file is finished reading and the `data` variable has what you need.

for example:

```
app.post('/top', function (req, res) {
    var obj;
    fs.readFile('./object.json', 'utf8', function (err, data) {
        if (err) throw err;
        obj = JSON.parse(data);
        console.log(obj["fruit"]);
        console.log(obj["thyroid"]);
        res.render(
          'disp.ejs',
          { 
            food: obj["fruit"]
            name: obj["thyroid"]

          }); // render
    });
});
```